# dataframe slicing and pivoting then into multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, slice

Ultimately I want to run a parametric var on stock data below

I have data in the form:

```
     Date       Symbol     ClosingPrice    Weight
0   7/22/2016      A         46.58         0.000002
1   7/25/2016      A         46.14         0.000002
2   7/26/2016      A         46.95         0.000002
3   7/27/2016      A         47.26         0.000002
4   7/28/2016      A         47.51         0.000002
5   7/22/2016     AA         10.57         0.000287
6   7/25/2016     AA         10.49         0.000287
7   7/26/2016     AA         10.67         0.000287
8   7/27/2016     AA         10.74         0.000287
9   7/28/2016     AA         10.68         0.000287
10  7/22/2016   AAAP         30.51         0.000003
11  7/25/2016   AAAP         31.02         0.000003
12  7/26/2016   AAAP         30.85         0.000003
13  7/27/2016   AAAP         30.97         0.000003
14  7/28/2016   AAAP         31.00         0.000003
```

I would like to create 2 separate dataframes as such:

```
date         A       AA      AAAP
7/22/2016   46.58   10.57   30.51
7/25/2016   46.14   10.49   31.02
7/26/2016   46.95   10.67   30.85
7/27/2016   47.26   10.74   30.97
7/28/2016   47.51   10.68   31
```

with symbols as the column headers

and

```
Symbol    Weight
A         0.00000166
AA        0.00028664
AAAP      0.00000326
```

The first dataframe will be used to calculate a variance/covariance matrix and the second dataframe represents the weights of each security in the stock portfolio (a parameter in the parametric VAR calculation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first table, you can pivot your original data frame to transform it from long to wide format on the first three columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df.iloc[:,0:3].pivot('Date', 'Symbol', 'ClosingPrice')

#   Symbol      A      AA    AAAP
#     Date          
#7/22/2016  46.58   10.57   30.51
#7/25/2016  46.14   10.49   31.02
#7/26/2016  46.95   10.67   30.85
#7/27/2016  47.26   10.74   30.97
#7/28/2016  47.51   10.68   31.00
```

The second table is the unique values of the second and fourth columns, so select them and `drop_duplicates` should be OK:

```
df.iloc[:,[1,3]].drop_duplicates()

#      Symbol     Weight
#0          A   0.000002
#5         AA   0.000287
#10      AAAP   0.000003
```

Comment: worked great, but how do I remove the 0,5,10 from the data display

Comment: Those are index of the data frame. Not exactly sure what you need, try `df.iloc[:,[1,3]].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)` or `df.iloc[:,[1,3]].drop_duplicates().set_index('Symbol')` and see if they are what you are looking for.